# How to fetch all product names of latest product version?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

In my table, I have two columns `prod_name` & `prod_version_number`. I want all `prod_name` of latest `prod_version_number`.

Update:

```
|prod_name| prod_version_number |
|   abc   |    1                |
|   abc   |    2                |
|   xyz   |    1                |
|   xyz   |    2                |
|   xyz   |    3                |
```

I want to fetch `abc` & `xyz` of `version_number` `2` & `3` respectively.
Here is my attempt.

```
select prod_name from t where prod_version_number= (select MAX(prod_version_number));
```

**NOTE** I know the rules of SOF. So can you undo the negative votes.

Comment: show your attempted query

Comment: Could you provide the complete structure of your table and any queries which you have attempted so far?  This will make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173260(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c2df/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE products ( prod_name, prod_version_number ) AS
          SELECT 'abc', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'abc', 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'xyz', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'xyz', 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'xyz', 3 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY prod_name ORDER BY prod_version_number DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   products p
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c2df/1/0)**:

```
| PROD_NAME | PROD_VERSION_NUMBER | RN |
|-----------|---------------------|----|
|       abc |                   2 |  1 |
|       xyz |                   3 |  1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT d.prod_name
 
FROM table d 
WHERE d.prod_version_number= (SELECT MAX(d1.prod_version_number) FROM table d1 WHERE d1.prod_name = d.prod_name )

Not sure if there is a more efficient way to do it by using GROUP BY clauses, will think about it and edit later if I find one. But for the moment, this should work.